# Cognos parameters dont display

Tags: cognos, cognos-10

I am using Cognos Report Studio 10.2.2. I have created a Cognos report that works great, it uses JavaScript to create a dynamic range of the last 30 days of the data requested by the user. At the top of the report I have two text items; one for the start date and one for the end date, they both use the ParamDisplayValue('parameter') to display the start and end dates. The dates display when the report is ran from Report Studio, however when I schedule the report in an email attachment (tried HTML and PDF) the start and end dates do not show up at all.

Any thoughts as to why this is?

Comment: The parameters don't display with Excel as the output either.

Comment: Oh I wonder if it has t do with JavaScript running in the browser but not outside of it. Email is outside of the browser so it then doesn't know what to display and shows blank.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with doing the date math in the JavaScript code.
I redid the date math using database functions innate to Cognos and put the results in text items on the report page and it now shows up in the email attachment.